# What scopes are needed to get a Gmail message content using the Gmail API?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-oauth, gmail-api

Is the view and modify (`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify`) OAuth scope enough to [get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get) an email message using the Gmail API and display the whole content in an app?

Answer (score 2):

The `readonly` scope is sufficient for your app instead of using the broader `modify` scope.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly
```

Please note that this is a Restricted scope and your app may need to pass through a security audit.

Comment: Was that a yes or a no?

Comment: The question was changed after this answer was written.